# What is the meaning of this special character '^?' in an ascii table?

Tags: c, ascii, cat

I'm trying to print non-printable characters in C files, but I can't print the given character because I don't know its meaning. I noticed this when I compared my program with cat.

cat -nt file.txt:

```
134  is 127 7f
```

cat -n file.txt:

```
134 ^? is 127 7f
```

Comment: " the given character " what given character? "my program" What program? Are we supposed to guess what it is you are trying to do? Please [edit] the question with a clear problem statement.

Comment: Do you want to write a C program to find non-printable characters or do you want to use some other tool to find non-printable characters in C source code? Or something else?

Comment: @Gerhardh  wrong, -t

Comment: @Gerhardh yes i do it with c, flag -t and -v and my program doesn't want to print that character.

Comment: @Flex1sh: I suspect you accidentally flipped the labeling of the two samples: The first one was probably produced by `cat -n` and the second one by `cat -nt`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Caret Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) (which `cat` uses when `-v` or `-t` is specified) `^?` represents [the DEL character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character) ([Unicode U+007F](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+007F), ASCII encoding 127 decimal, 0x7f in hex).

Comment: I agree with "the Caret Notation (which cat uses when -v or -t is specified) ^? represents the DEL character", yet OP reports `^?` with `-n` and  no `^?` with `-nt`.  Seems reversed to this answer.  Your thougths?

Comment: That detail was introduced by a recent edit by OP, I suspect that's a simple mistake.